# XAML User Control : Reuse the same instance

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

I am working on a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 project in C#. I have create a custom user control :

```
<UserControl x:Class="AppSeafileClient.Class.PivotHelpControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel  Background="#FFCDC8C8">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" Foreground="Black">If you are having trouble with this app, you can use the switch below to record information about how you use the app to send back to me.</TextBlock>
        <toolkit:ToggleSwitch 
            x:Name="toggle_debug" 
            Content="Off" IsChecked="False"  
            Foreground="Black"
            Unchecked="toggle_debug_Unchecked"
            Checked="toggle_debug_Checked">
            <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Information gathering" Foreground="Black" />
             </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.Header>            
        </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" Foreground="Black">Once you are done recording, add dome detail about the issue, then tap below to email the log back to me and I will be in touch :</TextBlock>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" Name="textblock_debug" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="150"></TextBox>
        <Button Name="debug_send" Click="debug_send_Click" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black">Send log</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Now, I want to use this control on 2 diferent page in my application. I add the control on the two page with this code :

```
<localClass:PivotHelpControl x:Name="myPivoteItemHelp" />
```

But, If i add text on the textbox on the page1, and I go on page2 I cannot see the text. I think the control is instancied two times.

How I can use on 2 pages the same control (Only 1 instance of the control) ?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure you can use the same instance of a control. I think you should use the same instance of a view model that would update the text box

Comment: You can bind the text to a property outside the user control so that all instances of the user control share the same text.

Comment: I can use global variable for saving the text. Is there an other way to use the same usercontrol on multiple page but only one instance at the time ?

Comment: In theory you could re-use the same instance.  You would need to manually remove the element from the one page, save the instance somewhere in a shared class, or maybe in a static class, and then add it to the other page.

Comment: It's probably safer to just save the text, though, unless you are experienced with Silverlight and know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: If you are using MVVM then surely through your viewmodel locator you can get the current instance of the usercontrol's viewmodel.